# Moving Background - Cross Browser

Tags: jquery, firefox, animation, cross-browser

I have a div with an image in the background, that slowly moves to the left. When it reaches the end of the image, it starts moving back to the right. It repeats this animation, over and over.

Here's the fiddle I have: http://jsfiddle.net/49H65/2/

It seems to work perfectly in Chrome and Safari, but I can't get it to work in Firefox.

Here's a snippet of the jQuery code that may be causing the issue, but I'm not 100% sure:

```
infiniteAnimate( $('header.nb-slider') ,{
    on:{
        'background-position-x': -slideAnimate,
        'background-position-y': 0
    },off:{
        'background-position-x': $('header.nb-slider').css('background-position-x'), //use style
        'background-position-y': $('header.nb-slider').css('background-position-y') //use style
    }
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok. Its Firefox not understanding `background-position-x` and `background-position-y`. You must feed FF with both values space-separated combined:

```
background-position: x-value + ' ' + y-value,
```

Unfortunately jQuery can't animate combined values, you have to write your own function or use a plugin. I tried [Keith Wood's jQuery Background Position](http://plugins.jquery.com/kbw.backgroundpos/), it seems to work in all browsers.